# HSSFWorkbook error shown in code

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

While creating a code for reading data from excel, for the code

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
```

An error is shown for input in eclipse. The error shown is "Input cannot be resolved to a type." I have read that by this statement we are creating an instance of the excel. But what should we provide as input for this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at POI busy developer's guide, there are plenty of examples for this: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

You need InputStream, OPCPackage or NPOIFSFileSytem for reading (this is example for NPOIFSFileSytem):

```
// HSSFWorkbook, File
NPOIFSFileSytem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("file.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot());
....
fs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the path of the excel file using inputstream,

```
FileInputStream input= null;
input= new FileInputStream(new File(path));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Input should be FileInputStream like

```
     String fileName="/home/hduser/file.xls";
     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream( new File( fileName ) );
     String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension( fileName );
     Workbook channelBook = getChannelWorkBook( fileExtension, file );

    /**
 * Get Workbook from extension
 */
private Workbook getChannelWorkBook( String fileExtension, FileInputStream file ) throws IOException
{
    if ( fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase( "XLS" ) )
        return new HSSFWorkbook( file );
    if ( fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase( "XLSX" ) )
        return new XSSFWorkbook( file );
    return null;
}
```